# /e modifier depreciated use preg_replace_callback instead PHP

Tags: php

I have a string that I need help converting to preg_replace_callback. Any help with an explanation would be helpful.

Thanks

```
preg_replace('/(?<=^|[\x09\x20\x2D])./e', 'strtoupper("\0")', strtolower(trim($match[1])));
```

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace-callback.php

Comment: Which part of the documentation are you having trouble with?

Comment: A little confused at the documentation because there isn't a before and after example.

Comment: Why do you need a before-and-after example? Don't you know what the current code does?

Comment: Nope I don't. I am testing a websocket server before modifying.

Answer (score 0):

Here is exact example from the manual with small change:

```
$string = preg_replace_callback(
        '/(?<=^|[\x09\x20\x2D])./',
        create_function(
            // single quotes are essential here,
            // or alternative escape all $ as \$
            '$matches',
            'return strtoupper($matches[0]);'
        ),
        $string
    );
```

or:

```
function myfunc($matches)
{
  return strtoupper($matches[0]);
}
$string = preg_replace_callback("/(?<=^|[\x09\x20\x2D])./", "myfunc", $string);
```

Comment: Replacing the `/e` modifier with `create_function` is pretty counter-productive, as both are essentially using `eval` underneath, with all the problems that entails. Use a real anonymous function, unless for some reason you need to simultaneously support PHP < 5.3 *and* some future version of PHP which doesn't have the `/e` modifier.